# IE11で document.XMLDocument や document.XSLDocument を使いたい

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xsl

IE8で動作させていたものを、IE11でも動作するように改修しています。

ASPにてDBへアクセスし取得した内容をXMLとして出力し、
リスト形式で表示するためにXSLを使用しています。
リストの動的ソートを行うためそのXSLからJavascriptを呼出しているのですが

```
var objXml = document.XMLDocument;
var objXsl = document.XSLDocument;
```

上記コードで各内容がundefinedとなってしまいました。

それぞれの内容を取得する方法、
もしくはXMLの内容を動的ソートさせる方法があれば教えてください。

---

追記

```
document.implementation.createDocument
```

上記コードでXMLDocumentは代替できましたが、XSLDocumentの実装方法がまだわかりません。
xsl:sortのみの実装では難しそうです。

---

追記２
実装は難しそうなので、今回はなしになりました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 単純なものならXSLで`xsl:sort`が使えるかもです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XMLDocument property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535155(v=vs.85).aspx)（のサンプルコード内のコメント）によると

> XML islands are not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and later.

です。具体的には[XML data islands are no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801224(v=vs.85).aspx)によるとIE10で削除されたとのことです。

とりあえず[MozillaでのXML データアイランドの利用](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla)というドキュメントがありました。